# Putting Umbraco Item in src of video

Tags: video, umbraco

I have a html video control below that I need the source to be an umbraco item. If there is no text it loads the textifempty url correctly but if it has text, when i inspect the video this is what it shows.

```
  <video controls autoplay width="100%">
                        <source src='<umbraco:Item field="video" textIfEmpty="http://content-packs.s3.amazonaws.com/Renters.mp4" runat="server"></umbraco:Item>'>
                      </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a razor macro.

```
<video controls autoplay width="100%"> 
       <source src="@Model.yourItemField" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I hope this solves your problem. :-)